# Make logstash add different inputs to different indices

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have setup logstash to use an embedded elastisearch.
I can log events.
My logstash conf looks thus:
https://gist.github.com/khebbie/42d72d212cf3727a03a0

Now I would like to add another udp input and have that input be indexed in another index.

Is that somehow possible?
I would do it to make reporting easier, so I could have system log events in one index, and business log events in another index.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use an `if` conditional in your output section, based on e.g. the message type or whatever message field is significant to the choice of index.

```
input {
  udp {
    ...
    type => "foo"
  }
  file {
    ...
    type => "bar"
  }
}

output {
  if [type] == "foo" {
    elasticsearch {
      ...
      index => "foo-index"
    }
  } else {
    elasticsearch {
      ...
      index => "bar-index"
    }
  }
}
```

Or, if the message type can go straight into the index name you can have a single output declaration:

```
elasticsearch {
  ...
  index => "%{type}-index"
}
```

Comment: Hi, How can I get two types of files streamed in by filebeat (such as a.log and b.cdr) to logstash and define them to be outputted to different indexes?

Comment: @Tomer Filebeat adds a field to each event containing the path of the file the event came from. You can apply the same idea as described above to that field. However, given the cost of indexes I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: The type attribute [is not encouraged](https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-type-parent-child-join-now-future-in-elasticsearch#sthash.GPJLwX6q.dpbs) and it also won't apply if you already have type field in your source (it doesn't override). So It's better to use tags or add_field instead.

Comment: @MagnusBäck is it possible to send the same doc to multiple indeces? For example, is it possible to specify an array for index? Or include multiple elasticsearch closures in the output section? This is useful for cases where we want to migrate away from one index to another, so we would direct the output to a new index while it is being written to the old index, and then phase out the old index after the port the data over.

Comment: @sbenderli To post a event to multiple indexes and/or ES clusters you need multiple elasticsearch outputs.

Comment: This works `index => "%{type}-index"`, but this doesn't `index => "%{type}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"` , do you know why?