# Logstash 6.1. - How crate input and index for each log

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I am trying to crate index for each input log file. This is my logstash configuration:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5044"
    }
    file{
        path => "/home/centos/logs/mylogs.log"
        id => "mylog"
    }
    file{
        path => "/home/centos/logs/syslog.log"
        id => "syslog"
    }
}
filter {
}
output {
    if [id] == "mylog" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => [ "10.206.81.246:9200", "10.206.81.236:9200", "10.206.81.243:9200" ]
            user => "Test"
            password => "123456"
            index => "mylog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}-%{id}"
        }
    }
    else if [id] == "syslog" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => [ "10.206.81.246:9200", "10.206.81.236:9200", "10.206.81.243:9200" ]
            user => "Test"
            password => "123456"
            index => "syslog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}-%{id}"
        }
    }
}
```

I do not understand how to crate separate input depends on path. I tried replace `%{id}` with `%{[id]}` or `%{+[id]}` but it does not work. Also tried use `type` or `tags`, the result is the same. I just created this indexes

```
mylog-2018.01.22-%{[id]}
mylog-2018.01.22-%{type}
mylog-2018.01.22-{id}
```

Is it even possible to create separate index for each log file? If it is, how to configure it? I perform some research of documentation or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146032/make-logstash-add-different-inputs-to-different-indices/27147688#27147688) and [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-configure-different-indexes-in-logstash/58665). Nothing works for me.

EDIT:
Output from Kibana record:

```
@timestamp      January 22nd 2018, 10:04:40.799
t @version      1
t _id       HwYcHWEB0LbLyxQz0EnW
t _index        syslog-2018.01.22
# _score        2
t _type     doc
t beat.hostname     filebeat-prod-fileabeat1.myname.osdc1.company.local
t beat.name     filebeat-prod-fileabeat1.myname.osdc1.company.local
t beat.version      6.1.1
t bytes     138
t client        12.4.14.27
t duration      0.23
t host      filebeat-prod-fileabeat1.myname.osdc1.company.local
t message       12.4.14.27 abcd /index.html 138 0.23
t method        abcd
# offset        379,156
t prospector.type       log
t request       /index.html
t source        /home/centos/logs/mylogs.log
t tags      beats_input_codec_plain_applied
```

Comment: (Sidenote: if your id field is neither "mylog" nor "syslog" you wont generate output. If you write filters later it might be useful to just drop those logs if they exist) This is a trivial solution, but you are using the variable in the index that you are using as a condition. Meaning you could change the index to "mylog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}-mylog". Don't know why you put mylog in there twice but there must be a reason. Your research is good, the index variable shouldn't do this. Does the record have 'id' as a field? (just a checklist question)

Comment: @MrSimple I have it twice just to see, if the new index is created, i just perform a lot of tests so there is already indices called `mylog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}`. The goal is to have names of indices based on service and type of logfile, but I have to start with something. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: You are using "id" in logstash config, but I see no such field in the record. There is an "_id" field but that is elasticsearch generated record id. Try and change the config to index => "mylog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}-%{method}", see what that does.

Comment: I tried  it with `mylog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}-%{method}`. No errors occur but also there is no new index in Kibana.

Comment: No new index in Kibana means that you tried to create a new index pattern and it wasn't there, right? (sry for asking, no new index in kibana and elastic is different, and I assume you checked that, but I want to make sure) Speaking about, do you have mylog-* as pattern? Because then my question is pointless. searching for _index: mylog-*-abcd should list those records that have 'abcd' as method.

Comment: Yes, I had right pattern and also I checked indices via `curl -XGET -u elastic:password "$(hostname -I):9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty"`. There is no new index. I checked it on elastiscearch machine, that why I used `$(hostname -I)`.

Comment: What I don't understand is how you get these records in the Kibana. Didn't you change the filter and use grok? I see the message and it's content in other fields (client, method, bytes, duration). The reason I ask this is every page I look at suggests that your index config should work.

Comment: I did not change the configuration file. The record in kibana is when I am using this format: `mylog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}`, it works. But i would like to change it, depends on a "type" or "id". The goal is to have separate index for each log file (or group of files). E.g.  apache-2018.24.2.-production1 . But this configuration does not separate it and I do not know why. Im using the same way of configuration according to documentation or other instructions mentioned in logstash discussion. When you see the kibana record, there is no syslog or mylog tag or id.

Comment: The last idea I have is to ask if you wrote new lines in the logfile after changing the configuration. It's a checklist question but I'm really running out of ideas.

Comment: I did not change any lines in logfile. The only files I worked with are `logstash.yml`, `jvm.options` and pipeline config in `/etc/logstash/conf.d` directory.

Comment: Well I guess I asked a dumb question since you are using the syslog.log file as input and that must have new lines from time to time. So it should have generated new events. That means I'm out of ideas. :/ Sry.

Comment: Well i always add new lines to my log files even to syslog. I create 2 files at my `/home/user/logs/` direcotry named `syslog.log` and `mylogs.log`. And before each test I add new lines there. I generate data in `mylogs.log` using : `for i in {0..9}; do echo "12.4.14.27 abcd /index.html 138 0.23" >> /home/user/logs/mylogs.log; done`  and in `syslog.log` using: `head -100 /var/log/messages-20180114 >> /home/user/logs/syslog.log`. So I always have new lines. I hope I will solve this and then I will place reply and explanation here. Thank you for your help.